# Abaqus CAE: Importing Deformed Geometry Issue

Tags: import, abaqus

I am running a simple bending analysis on a tube. I am interested in the deformed geometry, which I wish to import for further analysis. The method I'm using is:
**Import >> Part >> *.odb file >> Import Deformed Geometry >> Choose Step and Frame**

However, on doing so I notice that the imported part is no different from my original part (it is the same!). Although my analysis does show noticeable deformation.

Any input on where I'm going wrong. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

To import the geometry for futher analysis. In CAE select:
"File" >> "Import" >> "Part"
In the popup box select the ODB file type
and then select the results file you want to use the deformed geometry from.
The next popup box allows you to select "import defomred configuration" and lets you select which frame / step you require.
I hope this helps.